# Как отловить нажатие button в iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Вот кнопка:

```
<button name="btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" id="btn">Войти</button>
```

Эта кнопка с неконтролируемого мной домена.
Сам сайт вставлен в iframe.
Есть ли какой нибудь невероятный костыль который отловит клик по этой кнопке? Просто, насколько я знаю, в целях безопасности JSом нельзя подцепиться к ней.
Буду благодарен за любую идею.

Comment: Максимум что может сделать родительский фрейм - следить за location.href дочки, когда будет сделан переход на страницу по кнопке "войти" - дочка сменит url, что и можно отловить.

Comment: Можете помочь с кодом пожалуйста? Хотябы пример. Новичок в  JS. Писать пока мало могу, а вот поправить и понять что происходит в коде уже не проблема